# Compiling java.exe on Windows using Visual Studio?

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

The C source for java.exe is included in the JDK. Has anyone ever managed to compile this code to an executable on Windows using Visual Studio?
I've created a Win32 console app, added all the files from the 'launcher' folder in the java src.zip.

The code for java.exe includes 'jvm.h' which isn't in the JDK. Where can I find this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's unfortunately a lot more too it then that.

I'd recommend hitting up http://openjdk.org/ and starting from there...

On a larger note -- what is you're goal -- are you working on embedding java, creating some interesting native launcher, or just curious?

Comment: Yes, I was pretty sure there would be a long annoying road to getting this to compile :). My aim is to create a native launcher*. I'll take a look at the link you provided, thanks.

*So maybe a better question would be "How do I create a native launcher, so users can run an exe instead of running java.exe with a bunch of cmdline params".

Comment: Ah -- That makes things much easier.  Java lobby has a good article all about it. If you're writing an app with any meat on it's bones though you might want to look into using either the netbeans or eclipse RCP frameworks, both of which can solve the native launch issue. http://www.javalobby.org/articles/java2exe/